# Session.get not opening the right page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to open a link in a python script.

https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Automotive-Transmission-Fluid-Additives/zgbs/automotive/15718891/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_4_15718881#2

which when I copy into my browser shows the right page. However, when I open the link using python it just goes to

https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Automotive-Transmission-Fluid-Additives/zgbs/automotive/15718891/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_4_15718881

I tried using sessions with a few different headers and I also tried using requests.get. Am I just using the wrong headers? I was looking at the source code and there is an ajax url in addition to an href when you click the button to go from the first page to the second page so I was think that might be where I am going wrong?

CODE:

```
group_link = 'https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Automotive-Transmission-Fluid-Additives/zgbs/automotive/15718891/ref=zg_bs_nav_auto_4_15718881'

session.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1664.3 Safari/537.36',
'Accept':'text/html,application/json, text/javascript, application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6'})

link_2 = str(group_link) + "#2"
page_2 = session.get(link_2)
soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(page_2.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass certain *params* as the content is retrieved with an ajax request:

```
params = {"_encoding": "UTF8",
          "pg": "2",
          "ajax": "1"}

url = "https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Automotive-Transmission-Fluid-Additives/zgbs/automotive/15718891"

r = requests.get(url, params=params)
print(r.text)
```

Once you do that you will see you get the correct source returned. All you need is  `Best-Sellers-Automotive-Transmission-Fluid-Additives/zgbs/automotive/15718891` with the base amazon url. It does not show correctly because of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links), if you click edit you can see the proper url